# 4.7 GB download usage for realtime-database and I only have 2 numbers to query in the entire database, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have around 12k monthly active users, the app is an exchange rate app for only 2 currencies, so naturally, there isn't much to store, just 2 numbers, the buy rate and the sell rate.

However, my download usage per month is reaching 4.7GB, why?

This is the code that queries the database in my native android app (Java):

```
    private void getRefValue(DatabaseReference ref, TextView view) {
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            String textData;
            if (view.getTag().toString().equals("sellText")) {
                textData = "Sell: " + value;
                editor.putString("sell", value);
            } else {
                textData = "Buy: " + value;
                editor.putString("buy", value);
            }

            editor.apply();

            view.setText(textData);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.d("Failed to read", error.getMessage() + " " + error.getDetails());
        }

    });

}
```

Instead of making a separate function for each textView to be updated, I check the tag of the view to see if it's the sell view or the buy view, and I update its text accordingly, the `editor` variable is a sharedPreferences editor, I use shared preferences to show offline users the last available rate.

The database reference is passed as an argument when calling the function, it gets called twice, once for each entry in the DB.

Is my code doing anything wrong? I'm not very experienced with Java or native android.

Comment: It's hard to say where you downloads are coming from based on the information you shared. But Firebase downloads are fairly simple to estimate as: `number of users * number of connections * data per connection`, with the last one being `SSL overhead + number of reads * size of each read`. The SSL overhead is about 4K, and all the other numbers come from your code and users.

Comment: Following that equation, I'm supposed to be getting around 60-130MB per month, I'm getting around 152MB PER DAY, I'm currently trying to access my app's data/data folder to see why it increases 15MB in size each time I open the app, it also turns out that doing so on a Huawei phone or emulator is harder than invading Normandy.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue and faced huge billing from Firebase. Problem is that every time when a user comes into the application. It hits to the Firebase which uses data. Like you have used Shared Preferences for offline users but you just need to hit the event listener only when there is any change the database. For that you can make the versions if there is any change in the version it will check for the data otherwise it will show the data from shared preference only even if there is internet connection in the device.

I reduce the billing amount from 2Lacs to 2.5K only

Comment: What do you mean? I'm already using `onDataChange`

Comment: Yes, but as you said online user will get data from Firebase every time whenever user comes in the application. If you have 12000 user per month and if every user comes in the app 10 times in a day then you have 120000 user in that sense so to avoid call repetition call ondatachange only when there is change in the value in database

Comment: And how exactly do I know if the data is changed WITHOUT querying it? is there some sort of special listener that only queries data when it is changed? how do I know if the data has been changed or not?

Comment: Yes, Can you please tell me how many sells and rates one user is taking means to say is is there any Arraylist/ Hashmap?

Comment: No, just one buy rate consisting of a number, and another buy rate consisting of another number in the same structure